# Keyframe Animation affects other Elements

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm working on a WordPress website that includes a keyframe animation for a piece of text. In the keyframe animation, the text slides up as it fades in. The keyframe works great, but the only problem is that all the text and elements below the keyframe end up sliding up as well. They don't fade. but they slide up. I think this is because when the keyframe moves they adjust with the keyframe since the keyframe is basically adjusting the margin above them. How can I make it so that the elements below the keyframe animation ignore the moving margins that the keyframe has essentially created? Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<div class="homepagetitle">
    <div class="titlefade">
        <h2 class="titlefade"><?php echo $homepagetitle; ?></h2>
        <h2 class="homepagesubtitle"><?php echo $homepagesubtitle; ?></h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aboutus">
    <p class="aboutus"> <?php the_content(); ?></p>
</div>
```

And here is the style.css code that goes along with the code above:

```
h2.titlefade {
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-style: italic;
margin-top: 350px;
font-size: 65px;
word-spacing: 10px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
animation: titlefadeanimation ease 1.5s;
}

h2.homepagesubtitle {
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-size: 35px;
word-spacing: 5px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
animation: subtitlefade ease 1.5s;
}

@keyframes subtitlefade {
from {
    opacity: 0;
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
}
}

@keyframes titlefadeanimation {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 63
    margin-top: 525px;
}
50% {
    margin-top: 300px;
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 350px;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform: translateY` won't affect the flow of the page:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

h2.titlefade {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 65px;
  word-spacing: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  animation: titlefadeanimation ease 1.5s;
}

h2.homepagesubtitle {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  animation: subtitlefade ease 1.5s;
}

@keyframes subtitlefade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes titlefadeanimation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 63;
    transform: translateY(25px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="homepagetitle">
  <div class="titlefade">
    <h2 class="titlefade">
      Title
    </h2>
    <h2 class="homepagesubtitle">
      Subtitle
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aboutus">
  <p class="aboutus">
    Content
  </p>
</div>
```

You'll have to tweak it to how you want but you get the idea.

Also, with `@keyframes`, if you use `from` and the value for `to` is just the default, you can omit the `to` altogether.